# Java Dropwizard : Unable to import CSS / JS in html file when deployed on server

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, dropwizard

I have just built an api using dropwizard framework. It's my first time working with dropwizard and have descent understanding about spring. I am not an expert when it comes to front-end related stuff. I am experiencing an issue and is unable resolve it yet. In simple and short terms the problem is that CSS and JS are not being applied to my index.html when deployed on localhost:8080. However in IntelliJ it shows no import or path related error when importing js and css to my html (mustache) file and when I tested the html file by simply clicking it and opening it in chrome then css and js are being properly imported and applied. I don't know that there is path related issues or what, I have no idea. Also, but when istead of importing css and js as separte files, I inserted the css and js code in html itself then it works fine. I may be making a silly mistake or may be unaware about loading some static stuff concepts so kindly pardon and share the knowledge. Thanks.

below are the details

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Search Debug</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Search Debug Console</h1>
  <p></p>
  <form class="form" method="get" action="/debug">
    <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Query">
    <div>
      <p class="name-help">Please enter your query.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Debug">
  </form>
</div>
<p class="optimize">
  Optimized for Chrome & Firefox!
</p>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

js/**index.js**

```
$(".name").focus(function(){
$(".name-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideUp(500);
});

$(".email").focus(function(){
  $(".email-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".email-help").slideUp(500);
});
```

css/**style.css**

```
/*dark background to support form theme*/
body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/dark_wall.png);
}

/*sass variables used*/
/*site container*/
.wrapper {
  width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  font: 25px Oswald;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 1px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  font: 13px Open Sans;
  color: #6E6E6E;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 1px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 6px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 1px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #6E6E6E;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 1px 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#28D2DE), to(#1A878F));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#28D2DE 0%, #1A878F 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#28D2DE 0%, #1A878F 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#28D2DE 0%, #1A878F 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#28D2DE 0%, #1A878F 100%);
  font: 14px Oswald;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 1px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(50%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 4px 6px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 1px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease;
  -o-transition: 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name-help, .email-help {
  display: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.optimize {
  position: fixed;
  right: 3%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

[Screenshot when deployed on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpNAL.png)

[Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmTy5.png)

Sorry for the links though as I am new on stackoverflow and don't have enough reputation to embed the images here itself.

Comment: Start from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111061/25429). Serving static assets (javaScript, images, CSS files) requires explicit setup in Dropwizard.

Comment: I figured that out yesterday :) thanks for the link though :)